# Ploting a graph automatically using mouse coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent

In a matplotlib, I plotted a radargram, and what I want to do is to `read` and `plot` the coordinates of the mouse when it is moved on the radargram without clicking.

So to read mouse coordinate I worked with `mouseevent`.

This is my code:

```
def readfile():
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    Data = df.iloc[::1, ::1]
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(Data, aspect='auto', cmap='bone')
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)
    plt.show()
def mouse_move(event):
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(x, y)
```

after compiling the program, I got this:

[image]

When I passed my mouse on the graph I got these coordinate without clicking:

```
2218.1290322580644 174.3311688311688
2138.1129032258063 177.76731601731598
2021.7258064516127 183.2651515151515
1832.5967741935483 190.8246753246753
1628.9193548387098 199.07142857142856
1403.4193548387098 206.63095238095235
1207.016129032258 212.81601731601728
1039.709677419355 219.68831168831167
814.209677419355 226.56060606060606
603.2580645161291 231.37121212121212
428.6774193548388 234.12012987012986
```

Now what I want to do is every time when I move my mouse on the plot above I should plot the specific coordinate in a different graph automatically.

Any help?

Comment: I tried to adapt your solution to my program but didn't seccuded, please see my answer to see mu full program

Comment: I hadn't understood your question correctly, so please edit it to clarify what you want to plot exactly. Is it an horizontal slice of Data?