# How to plot an automatic graph using mouse without clicking MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm looking to plot Data automatically using mouse without clicking From a DZT file.
i Created a program in order to plot data as you can see in this graph:[image]

As you can see in this picture, `x axes` going from 0 to 3525 ans every `x` is a signal so i have more than 3500 signals making this graph.

for exemple if i want to see the signal of `x=999`, it looks like this.[image]

what i want really to do is every time when i pass my mouse without clicking on the graph it should plot it's signal automatically .

i try to use a lot of methods but rally i dont know how to do it.

i'll be grateful for your help

this is my file:
https://www.grosfichiers.com/mvabGETFfna

This is my program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from readgssi import readgssi

root = Tk()
root.title("IHM")
root.geometry("1000x800")

Resources_frame = LabelFrame(root, bd=2, relief=GROOVE, text="Conversion Area")
Resources_frame.place(x=5, y=5, width=250, height=80)

lbl_ra = Label(Resources_frame, text="Select your File ")
lbl_ra.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
lbl_ra = Label(Resources_frame, text="Convert Selected file ")
lbl_ra.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
NumberOfSimples = ''
DataAScan = ''
Data = ''
xData = ''
xAxes = ''


def ReadDZT():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)

    print(file_extension)
    if file_extension == '.DZT':
        messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "Your DZT File Has Been Selected Successfully")
        hdr, arrs, gps = readgssi.readgssi(infile=file_path, verbose=True)

        TimeRange = hdr['rhf_range']
        Samples = hdr['rh_nsamp']

        X_Axes = np.array(range(0, Samples))
        xAxes = X_Axes[2::1]

        df = pd.DataFrame(arrs[0])
        Data = df.iloc[2::1, 0::1]
        fig2 = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(xAxes, Data[999])
        plt.show()

        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(Data, aspect='auto', cmap='bone')
        plt.show()

    elif file_extension == '.csv':
        messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "Your CSV File Has Been Selected Successfully")
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        NumberOfSimples = df.iloc[2::1, 0]
        Data = df.iloc[::1, ::1]
        DataAScan = df.iloc[2::1, 999]
        fig1 = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(NumberOfSimples, DataAScan)
        plt.show()
        fig2 = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(Data, aspect='auto', cmap='bone')
        plt.show()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("WARNING", "You Have Been Selected a Different Format")


# =============Resources Buttons================#
btn_rs = Button(Resources_frame, relief=GROOVE, padx=8, pady=1, text="Browse", command=ReadDZT).grid(row=0,
                                                                                                     column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to call the function with the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the previous question [Ploting a graph automatically using mouse coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263030/ploting-a-graph-automatically-using-mouse-coordinate) (and I think this question should have been an edit of it), the mouse motion can be monitored with `plt.connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)`. The slice of `Data` to be plotted in `fig2` simply corresponds to the x-coordinate of the mouse, that is `Data[int(event.xdata)]` in `mouse_move(event)`.

Therefore, in `mouse_move(event)`, you:

1. Clear the axis: `ax2.clear()` (where `ax2` is the `AxesSubplot` object of `fig2`)
2. Plot the slice `ax2.plot(self.xAxes, self.Data[int(event.xdata)])`
3. Update the figure `fig2.canvas.draw_idle()`

However, I had issues with using simultaneously the matplotlib figures and the tkinter GUI because of the separate event loops. Therefore I embedded the figures in the tkinter GUI directly (see e.g. https://matplotlib.org/3.4.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).

I also put the graph related code in a class to keep the loaded data in attributes to avoid using global variables.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import os
from readgssi import readgssi


class Graphs(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        # data
        self.Data = []
        self.xData = []
        self.xAxes = []
        self.line = None

        # figure1 : 2D data map
        self.fig1 = Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig1.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig1, self)
        self.canvas1.draw()
        self.canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(sticky='ewsn')
        self.toolbar1 = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas1, self, pack_toolbar=False)
        self.toolbar1.grid(sticky="ew")

        # figure 2: slice plot
        self.fig2 = Figure()
        self.ax2 = self.fig2.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig2, self)
        self.canvas2.draw()
        self.canvas2.get_tk_widget().grid(sticky='ewsn')
        self.toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas2, self, pack_toolbar=False)
        self.toolbar2.grid(sticky="ew")

        # bind plotting to mouse motion
        self.canvas1.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.mouse_move)

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        x = event.xdata
        if len(self.Data) and x is not None:  # there is something to plot
            self.ax2.clear()
            x = int(x)
            self.ax2.plot(self.xAxes, self.Data[x])
            self.line.set_data([x, x], [len(self.Data), 0])
            self.canvas1.draw_idle()
            self.canvas2.draw_idle()

    def readDZT(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)

        if file_extension == '.DZT':
            messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "Your DZT File Has Been Selected Successfully")
            hdr, arrs, gps = readgssi.readgssi(infile=file_path, verbose=True)

            Samples = hdr['rh_nsamp']

            X_Axes = np.array(range(0, Samples))
            self.xAxes = X_Axes[2::1]
            df = pd.DataFrame(arrs[0])
            self.Data = df.iloc[2::1, 0::1]

            # clear plots
            self.ax1.clear()
            self.ax2.clear()
            # plot slice
            self.ax2.plot(self.xAxes, self.Data[999])
            self.canvas2.draw_idle()
            # plot 2D map
            self.ax1.imshow(self.Data, aspect='auto', cmap='bone')
            self.line = self.ax1.plot([999, 999], [len(self.Data), 0], 'r')[0]
            self.ax1.set_ylim(len(self.Data), 0)
            self.canvas1.draw_idle()

        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("WARNING", "You Have Been Selected a Different Format")



root = tk.Tk()
root.title("IHM")
root.geometry("1000x800")

Resources_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, text="Conversion Area")
Resources_frame.place(x=5, y=5, width=250, height=80)

tk.Label(Resources_frame, text="Select your File ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(Resources_frame, text="Convert Selected file ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

graphs = Graphs(root)


btn_rs = tk.Button(Resources_frame, relief=tk.GROOVE, padx=8, pady=1, text="Browse",
                   command=graphs.readDZT).grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i tried to execute the program, but it gives me an error.
`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to put `len()` around `Data` to check if it is empty

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful :)
thanks to you, Finally it works

Comment: I just realised that th radargram is inversed in the `y axes` it should start from 250 to 0
not the inverse

Comment: @JosephDougmi I hadn't paid attention to the y-axis, now it is fixed (I just switched the limits in `self.ax1.set_ylim(len(self.Data), 0)`)

Comment: i switched the `y axes` but its still the same take a look to my first graph the darker line must be on the top not on the buttom, it's like inversed (

Comment: @JosephDougmi I have fixed the code and updated the screenshot, I think the y-axis is in the correct direction now.

Comment: @j_d321, it's Working Perfectly, thank you a lot ))

Comment: @j_d321, can you see this for me please [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319112/cant-replot-a-graph-on-the-same-figure-matplotlib], because i want to try another methode, my only problem in this methos it's how to update the graph, can you take a look for it please