# Can't replot a graph on the same figure MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

First I want to thank a user @j_4321 that helps me a lot in this problem [How to plot an automatic graph using mouse without clicking MATPLOTLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299071/how-to-plot-an-automatic-graph-using-mouse-without-clicking-matplotlib).

I really understand your method, but I want to do this method using functions  only in order to familiarize with python.

but with this method every time when I move my mouse, a new figure pops up and what I want to do is to replot on the same figure.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import os
from readgssi import readgssi

# data
Data = []
xData = []
xAxes = []


def readDZT():
    global xAxes, Data
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)

    if file_extension == '.DZT':
        messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "Your DZT File Has Been Selected Successfully")
        hdr, arrs, gps = readgssi.readgssi(infile=file_path, verbose=True)

        Samples = hdr['rh_nsamp']

        X_Axes = np.array(range(0, Samples))
        xAxes = X_Axes[2::1]
        df = pd.DataFrame(arrs[0])
        Data = df.iloc[2::1, 0::1]
        fig1 = plt.figure()
        # clear plots
        plt.clf()
        # plot 2D map
        plt.imshow(Data, aspect='auto', cmap='bone')
        plt.connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)
        fig1.canvas.draw_idle()
        plt.show()

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("WARNING", "You Have Been Selected a Different Format")


def mouse_move(event):
    x = event.xdata
    print(x)
    if len(Data) and x is not None:  # there is something to plot
        fig2 = plt.figure()
        plt.clf()
        x = int(x)
        plt.plot(xAxes, Data[x])
        fig2.canvas.draw_idle()
        plt.show()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("IHM")
root.geometry("1000x800")

Resources_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, text="Conversion Area")
Resources_frame.place(x=5, y=5, width=250, height=80)

tk.Label(Resources_frame, text="Select your File ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(Resources_frame, text="Convert Selected file ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

btn_rs = tk.Button(Resources_frame, relief=tk.GROOVE, padx=8, pady=1, text="Browse",
                   command=readDZT).grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why a new figure pops up every time you move the mouse is because moving the mouse triggers `mouse_move()` and inside this function, you create a new figure with `fig2 = plt.figure()`.

To avoid that, you can create both figures outside the functions. But then, when you plot the graphs, you have to replace `plt.imshow` by `ax1.imshow` and `plt.plot` by `ax2.plot` to get the graphs on the right figure. And also `plt.clf()` has to be replaced by `ax1.clear()`/`ax2.clear()`.

Finally, you can remove the `plt.show()` from `mouse_move()` since matplotlib event loop is already running (called in `readDZT()`). The call to `plt.show()` freezes the tkinter GUI as long as the plots are displayed so I also added `root.update_idletasks()` in  `readDZT()` to make the messagebox disappear before launching matplotlib's event loop.

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import os
from readgssi import readgssi

# data
Data = []
xData = []
xAxes = []

# create plots
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

def readDZT():
    global xAxes, Data
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)

    if file_extension == '.DZT':
        messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "Your DZT File Has Been Selected Successfully")
        hdr, arrs, gps = readgssi.readgssi(infile=file_path, verbose=True)

        Samples = hdr['rh_nsamp']

        X_Axes = np.array(range(0, Samples))
        xAxes = X_Axes[2::1]
        df = pd.DataFrame(arrs[0])
        Data = df.iloc[2::1, 0::1]
        # clear plots
        ax1.clear()
        ax2.clear()
        # plot 2D map in ax1
        ax1.imshow(Data, aspect='auto', cmap='bone')
        fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)
        fig1.canvas.draw_idle()
        fig2.canvas.draw_idle()
        # force update of tkinter GUI before launching matplotlib's event loop
        root.update_idletasks()
        plt.show()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("WARNING", "You Have Been Selected a Different Format")


def mouse_move(event):
    x = event.xdata
    print(x)
    if len(Data) and x is not None:  # there is something to plot
        ax2.clear()  # clear second plot
        x = int(x)
        ax2.plot(xAxes, Data[x])  # plot slice in ax2
        fig2.canvas.draw_idle()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("IHM")
root.geometry("1000x800")

Resources_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, text="Conversion Area")
Resources_frame.place(x=5, y=5, width=250, height=80)

tk.Label(Resources_frame, text="Select your File ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(Resources_frame, text="Convert Selected file ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

btn_rs = tk.Button(Resources_frame, relief=tk.GROOVE, padx=8, pady=1, text="Browse",
                   command=readDZT).grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ah Ok, i understand now, thank you so much it was so clear.
it works fine